# If $f(x,y)$ is a function that its contour lines are straight, is it necessary looks like $f(x,y) = ax + by + c$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, examples-counterexamples, graphing-functions

If $f(x,y)$ is a function that its [contour lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contour_line) are straight, is it necessary looks like $f(x,y) = ax + by + c$?

Well, in the answer is no. it is written that $e^{x+y}$ for every $(x,y)$ has straight contour lines. I'm not sure they're correct, can you explain or give another example of a function which its contour lines are straight? or explain how to solve this question efficiently?

Thank you very much in advance.

**Edit:** In wolfram alpha, $e^{(x+y)}$ are straight lines, but how can I know that during an exam where I don't have any tools except a calculator?

Comment: Maybe other functions of the form $f(x,y)=g(x+y)$ could work, too (at least if $g \colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is injective.) Or functions like $f(x,y)=e^x$ or $f(x,y)=x^3$, which depend only on $x$

Comment: @MartinSleziak How about $f(x,y) = x, \forall (x,0)$?

Comment: What is $\forall(x,0)$?

Comment: @KennyLau for every point which $x$ can be any value, and $y$ must be zero.

Comment: @KennyLau Why would substraction of derivations by $x$ and by $y$ that gives zero inforce straight counter lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contour line is defined as $\{ (x,y) | f(x,y) = constant \}$. So for $e^{x+y}=C$, you get $x+y = \ln C$, which is a straight line. The answer is correct. Another strange example would be $(15x+6y)^{100}$.